# Sending and receiving different Types with httpclient.post in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, post, angular-httpclient

I have the requirement to call a web service where I send a POST request with a User object and it returns me a LogToken object.

I can't find how to do this with Angular httpClient as it seems to expect the same type sent and received. If I do the following I get an error:

```
  public login(user: User): Observable<LoginToken> {
    return this._httpClient.post<User>(this._authenticationServiceUrl, user);
  }
```

> Error TS2322  Type 'Observable{User}' is not assignable to type
>   'Observable{LoginToken}'.

As I'm pretty new to this technology I guess I'm doing something wrong but I'm unsure about what. Is it wrong to receive a different type from a POST request?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The type parameter passed to the `post` is the one you expect to get back. So do

```
public login(user: User): Observable<LoginToken> {
    return this._httpClient.post<LoginToken>(this._authenticationServiceUrl, user);
}
```

Comment: Seems like this is the correct answer. But isn't redundant to add a type to the `POST` response and to the `login()` method response?

Comment: In general you are right. But in this case I don't think a client can try to be logged in with two types

Comment: Yes but, if the returned object from the BE doesn't match the type specified in `Observable<LoginToken>` an error will be thrown, so, specifying it also in `post<LoginToken>` I find it redundant. Or am I missing something? Why would this approach be more effective than just specifying the type in the `Observable`?

Comment: Can you clarify the last sentence a bit?

Comment: Yes sure, if you remove `post<LoginToken>()` and simply use `post()`. You are not checking the type of the response received by the BE during the HTTP call itself, but by having `Observable<LoginToken>`, a compiler error will appear if the object received and, therefore, streamed by the Observable does not match `LoginToken`. So, we could safely just type the response in the wrapper method, in this case `login()` rather than in both places.

Comment: Understood. The effectiveness is in the type checking. When you use typescript, you need to use all its power. One more thing that the client must know what type the server returns. So if you will get an error, this indicates that you don't understand the server and need to look at your types one more time

Answer (score 0):

To make a HTTP Request in angular 2, Please follow below steps

1.Import Http Module from @angular/http library

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
```

2.Create an instance of Http using Dependancy Injection in the Constructor

```
constructor(private http : Http) { }
```

3.Call the http POST and use Promise to handle asynchronous call

```
public login(user: User): Promise<LoginToken> {
    return this.http.post(this._authenticationServiceUrl, user).toPromise()
    .then(**HandleData**)
    .catch(**HandleError**);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Suren. Then Better We can use HttpClient

Comment: import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

Comment: constructor(
  private http: HttpClient){}